# The onregistered event does not occur after upgrading to Android Pie

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap

We created a hybrid app using phonegap.
So far, I've used GCM plugin well.
However, if you upgrade your phone with Android pie (9.0), the onRegistered event will not occur.
I do not go out on the issue when I google it.
I seek advice from your advisers.

```
public void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onRegistered: "+ regId);
    JSONObject json;
    try
    {
        json = new JSONObject().put("event", "registered");
        json.put("regid", regId);

        Log.v(TAG, "onRegistered: " + json.toString());

        // Send this JSON data to the JavaScript application above EVENT should be set to the msg type
        // In this case this is the registration ID
        PushPlugin.sendJavascript( json );
    }
    catch( JSONException e)
    {
        // No message to the user is sent, JSON failed
        Log.e(TAG, "onRegistered: JSON exception");
    }
}
```